# Why conditional GAN does not need "negative sample"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, gan

In conditional GAN's implementation, the inputs and labels of the discriminator are (fake_image, corresponding_condition, 0) and (real_image, corresponding_condition, 1). For example, (fake_dog, dog, 0), (real_dog, dog, 1). So why don't we need samples whose image does not correspond to its condition. For example, a dog with a cat condition? Under such circumstances, discriminator should give a negative response.

Without the negative pairs, the generator can simply neglect the condition and produce whatever it likes. The discriminator can distinguish the real and fake only by the image's content, also neglecting its condition.